# Can I use Adobe's (Satellite) Dynamic Tag Manager to set basic Adobe Analytics (Omniture) vars?

Tags: adobe-analytics

Is it possible to use Adobe DTM (aka Satellite Tag Manager) to set basic Omniture/Adobe Analytics variables, like pageName, so we don't need to place this code on the page?

Comment: yes this is possible.

Comment: Are you also loading Analytics through DTM as a product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to load the "Analytics" tool to DTM to begin setting up Adobe Analytics variables. The nice thing about DTM is you do not need to migrate all of your analytics code to DTM all at once, you can migrate in steps as long as you tell DTM analytics code already exists on the page.

There are great videos here (under Dynamic Tag Management) which walk you through the setup of DTM and the configuration of the Analytics tool. https://outv.omniture.com/

Comment: Thanks, Laura. I appreciate the link, and your expertise!

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest benefits of DTM is to be able to do this in a very easy-to-do manner.  You can create data elements to define the different pieces of data, and then use those data elements to populate the SiteCatalyst variables in rules.  It greatly simplifies an implementation and is much faster than having to add code to each page.  Plus it removes the need for developers having to put props, eVars, and events on a page.  They just put a data layer (preferably in JSON) with all of the data you want to send to SiteCatalyst.  The structure of the data layer is unimportant, and they can use any naming format they want.